# Jface Treeviewer lazyloading RCP java

Tags: treeview, jface, rcp

In RCP jfacetreeview suppose I have 1000 rows, but I want to load only 50 rows first, and then, when I click on (more...) I need another 50 to load. 
Like I need virtual tree, so I can insert more data but I can load data when I need that.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJFaceTableAdvanced/article.html
tried lazy loading but don't know how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? To help us help you, please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: For a tree you use `ILazyTreeContentProvider`, see https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/viewers/Snippet047VirtualLazyTreeViewer.java?id=R4_3

Comment: i got tree using lazycontent provider...but how i can decide that i need 10 child then by cling next i need another 10 like wise

Comment: paging for tree viewer...how to do that???please help me..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a special tree node which always there at the bottom with text "Show More ...".  And load more content when it get clicked.  And move that node to the new end of rows.